# How to resolve mutual references between two shared library?

Tags: c, unix, linker, shared-libraries

First, I know the title of the question is not the best. Likely, these concepts are well-known. Hence, let's try to be clear now.

I have a shared library(native Java agent) which can load additional shared libraries as plugins. In short, **libCore.so** does at load time:

```
H = dlopen("libPlugin1.so", RTLD_LAZY)
routine = dlsym("registration_function", H)
routine(struct Plugin)
```

That part is working, my problem is in the interaction between plugins and the core.
For instance, the core has a function with the name **getDataFromTag**. When the plugins tries to call such a function I get the following error:

```
java: symbol lookup error: libplugin1.so: undefined symbol: getDataFromTag
```

Take into account that the problem is with native code, there is no Java-Code involved in the interaction.

Now, it seems to me that the linker is not fixing the imported symbols in **libPlugin1.so** when I perform the dlopen. My questions are:

- Do I need to declare the imported symbols in libPlugin1.so? How?
- Do I need to declare the exported symbols in libCore.so? How?
- Do I have to link the plugin with a dependencies to the core? How? Isn't that weird? Sort of cyclic dependencies?
- Is this relate to the option `-z defs`? How can use that? How it does work?

Additional points, every plugin has a function with the name `registration_function`. So, I cannot use RTLD_GLOBAL.

Comment: Have you tried using `RTLD_NOW` instead of `RTLD_LAZY`? I'm not 100% sure this will work but should probably resolve *getDataFromTag* proactively, so it's available for the plugins.

Comment: No, it fails at load time now (during the dlopen). But it is the same problem. It cannot locate a symbol defined within the core. I also try RTLD_GLOBAL with a single plugin and it sill fails.

Comment: quite the same has worked for me recently (using `RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL`). But I think it might dpened on the way your libCore.so has been linked. What platform are you on and what linker switches have you used?

Comment: I am using Linux. I am using:`LDFLAGS=-Wl,-soname=$(LIBRARY) -static-libgcc` and `LIBRARIES=-lc -ldl`. I cannot use RTLD_GLOBAL because plugins share the name of some symbols.

Comment: that's my linker switches on linux: `-shared` instead of `-static-libgcc` for libCore.so and an additional `-lCore`  for libPlugin. For binaries that statically linked libCore.a I also needed `-rdynamic`

Comment: @Ingo: As you said, adding `-lCore` to libPlugins solves the problem. Using `-shared` has no effect, at least visible to me.

Comment: right, I've just listed all differences between your linker switches and mine. Now we also know what exactly makes the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't know if it is the best. Here it goes.

```
Do I have to link the plugin with a dependencies to the core? How? Isn't that weird? Sort of cyclic dependencies?
```

That's exactly what I did. I included in plugins the following linker switches:

```
LDFLAGS +=-L$(PATH_TO_CORE)
# Libraries we are dependent on
LIBRARIES+=-lCore
```

In the core library I am using `RTLD_LAZY` for performance and `RTLD_LOCAL` to avoid symbols' redefinition.